# Null pointer exception from final variable within runnable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8

I have code that runs a portfolio of algorithms on a given problem, and then as soon as one algorithm finds the answer to a problem, the program continues. The other algorithms in the portfolio get voluntary signals to terminate, and the main thread of execution goes on.

One user of this code is sending me a stacktrace with a NullPointerException on the line 
"resultReference.set(solverResult);"
As you can see from the code below, resultReference is a final variable and is initialized immediately. I don't see how it could possibly ever become null. I've spent a long time trying to reproduce the problem on my end to no avail. The line numbers on the user's stacktrace match up with the line numbers on my code. The user reports having seen the error on 3 different occasions, but infrequently (this does not happen every time a problem is solved), so maybe its some sort of race condition. This is with jdk 1.8_25.

Am I right in assuming that this error should be impossible because the variable is final? I'm not sure what to make of this stack trace and wanted some reassuring that it should be impossible.

```
public class ParallelSolver {

private final ListeningExecutorService executorService;
private final AtomicReference<Throwable> error;
private final List<Solver> solvers;
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParallelSolver.class);

public ParallelSolver(int threadPoolSize, List<Solvers> solvers) {
    executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize));
    error = new AtomicReference<>();
    this.solvers = solvers;
}

public SolverResult solve(Problem p) {
    final AtomicReference<SolverResult> resultReference = new AtomicReference<>();
    final List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    final Semaphore workDone = new Semaphore(0);
    try {
        // Submit one job per each solver in the portfolio
        solvers.forEach(solver -> {
            final ListenableFuture<Void> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                SolverResult solverResult = solver.solve(p);
                if (solverResult.isConclusive()) {
                    log.debug("Signalling the blocked thread to wake up!");
                     // NPE HERE ON THIS LINE
                    resultReference.set(solverResult);
                    workDone.release(solvers.size());
                }
                log.debug("Releasing a single permit as the work for this thread is done.");
                workDone.release(1);
                log.debug("Job ending...");
                return null;
            });
            futures.add(future);
            Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    if (t instanceof CancellationException) {
                        return;
                    }
                    error.compareAndSet(null, t);
                    // Wake up the main thread (if it's still sleeping)
                    workDone.release(solvers.size());
                }
            });
        });
        // Wait for a thread to complete solving and signal you, or all threads to timeout
        log.debug("Main thread going to sleep");
        workDone.acquire(solvers.size());
        log.debug("Main thread waking up, checking for errors then cancelling futures");
        checkForErrors();
        // cancel any still to be launched futures
        futures.forEach(future -> future.cancel(false));
        log.debug("Returning now");
        return resultReference.get() == null ? SolverResult.createTimeoutResult() : resultReference.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while running parallel job", e);
    }
}

/**
 * We want a fail-fast policy, but java executors aren't going to throw the exception on the main thread.
 * We can't call Future.get() and check for errors, because that might block.
 * So we set a variable when an error occurs, and check it here.
 */
private void checkForErrors() {
    if (error.get() != null) {
        log.error("Error occured while executing a task", error.get());
        throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred while executing a task", error.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: The code as written, `solvers` is never initialized so it is always `null`. And I have no idea what `workDone` is.

Comment: Thanks, corrected - issues in copying and pasting the code. workDone is a semaphore that is used to make sure that the main thread blocks until either everyone times out or else one algorithm finds an answer.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? One question is whether the NPE originates at the marked line or somewhere within the `AtomicReference` code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is almost what you want using akka:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import scala.concurrent.Await;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.pattern.Patterns;
import akka.util.Timeout;


public class AlgorithmTester extends UntypedActor
{
    public AlgorithmTester(){}
    
    public static class RegisterResultListener
    {
        
    }
    
    public static class Result
    {
        final double result;
        public Result(double result)
        {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }
    
    public static interface Algorithmable
    {
        public Result solve();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class AlgorithmsToTest extends ArrayList<Algorithmable> {
    }
    
    public static class AlgorithmRunner extends UntypedActor
    {
        
        public AlgorithmRunner(){}

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception
        {
            if (msg instanceof Algorithmable)
            {
                Algorithmable alg = (Algorithmable) msg;
                getSender().tell(alg.solve(), getSelf());
            }
        }
    }
    
    List<ActorRef> runners = new ArrayList<ActorRef>();
    List<ActorRef> resultListeners = new ArrayList<ActorRef>();
    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception
    {
        
        if (msg instanceof RegisterResultListener)
        {
            resultListeners.add(getSender());
        }
        else if (msg instanceof AlgorithmsToTest)
        {
            AlgorithmsToTest algorithms = (AlgorithmsToTest) msg;
            for (Algorithmable algorithm : algorithms)
            {
                ActorRef runner = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(AlgorithmRunner.class));
                runners.add(runner);
                runner.tell(algorithm, getSelf());
            }
            getSelf().tell(new RegisterResultListener(), getSender());
        }
        else if (msg instanceof Result)
        {
            for (ActorRef runner : runners)
            {
                getContext().stop(runner);
            }
            runners.clear();
            
            for (ActorRef l : resultListeners)
            {
                l.tell(msg, getSelf());
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("AlogrithmTest");
        ActorRef tester = system.actorOf(Props.create(AlgorithmTester.class), "algorithmTest");
        
        Algorithmable a1 = new Algorithmable()
       {

            public Result solve() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new Result(1100.0);
                }
        };
        
        Algorithmable a2 = new Algorithmable()
       {

            public Result solve() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new Result(330.0);
                }
        };
        
       Algorithmable a3 = new Algorithmable()
       {

            public Result solve() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new Result(1000);
                }
        };
        
        AlgorithmsToTest algorithmsToTest = new AlgorithmsToTest();
        algorithmsToTest.add(a1);
        algorithmsToTest.add(a2);
        algorithmsToTest.add(a3);
        
        Timeout t = new Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(tester, algorithmsToTest, 100000);
        try {
            Result response = (Result)Await.result(future, t.duration());
            System.out.println(response.result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Continuing on");
        system.terminate();
        System.out.println("Terminated");
    }
}
```

However there is no way in akka to kill actors whilst they are processing messages, you'll note that this program continues executing whilst the actors are processing the other algorithms, even though the first answer was already found.
Killing threads is never nice so there is no nice solution to your question. You could tag on a System.exit(0) at the end of the main method I guess, or have a horrible atomic variables somewhere in your algorithms were they are iterating and throw exceptions, or have them as threads and kill them, all not very nice ):
Me personally I'd use the System.exit(0) if you can get away with it.

Look this is alternative code to what you want to do, without having atomic variables, atomic variables and locks and all that other stuff is very dangerous and error prone, this is a much cleaner answer. All that is needed to change this code to match what you want is merely the Result, or Algorithmable interface, and provide all the implementations you want this does exactly what you asked. If this downvote infers that you think atomic variables are preferred to an actor based model then I suggest you do some reading.
Asker does not even give the stacktrace for the null pointer exception so it is not possible to directly address this issue.